# Laravel failed job doesn't send notification

Tags: laravel

When a job fails my notification doesn't arrive, and I'm not sure why. In my Job I have:

```
use Notification;
use App\Notifications\MonitoringMessage;

public function handle()
{
 asdf;
}

public function failed(Exception $exception)
{
  $message = ':warning: A job failed.';
  Notification::route('slack', config('services.slack.webhook'))->notify(new MonitoringMessage($message));
}
```

The notification is not queued using `use Queueable;` etc because I've read that that might cause the issue because the job itself is also queued.

The code above will cause the job to fail of course, and I can see it in the failed_jobs table, but the notification is not send. If I put the notification code somewhere else (eg in a controller) and execute it the notification is sent so that code is correct.

Comment: have you tried writing to the log from the failed method to see if it's being executed?

Comment: probably `asdf;` fails in `handle()` function lol

Comment: @Buglinjo yes it does :-). My assumption was that because it fails the job in `handle()`, the `failed()` method is executed (that's how I read the docs) but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Buglinjo has a point. Try something that fails but is not a syntax error. `$result = 1/0;` would probably do. No syntax but a division by zero error.

Comment: Use `Log` function to log an error message, or install Laravel `dump-server` and `dd($exception->getMessage());` and it will display in your running console window.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey thanks, one step closer. I now get `Argument 1 passed to App\Jobs\MyJob::failed() must be an instance of App\Jobs\Exception, instance of ErrorException given`

Comment: I changed `failed(Exception $exception)` to `failed()` as I don't use the Exception details and now it works. @DimitriMostrey feel free to post an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: A syntax error will be failed until Laravel is booted. Laravel jobs are booted with Laravel so if you use something which throws Exception it should go to failed method. try `throw new Exception('a message');` in handle method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any job is handled through the `handle()` method. Make sure this method doesn't fail because of a syntax mistake. If your code fails on a syntax error, the rest of you code can't possibly be executed as it will never be processed. Force a conceptual mistake, for example a division by zero forced error:

```
use Notification;
use App\Notifications\MonitoringMessage;

public function handle()
{
 $result = 1/0;
}

public function failed()
{
  $message = ':warning: A job failed.';
  Notification::route('slack', config('services.slack.webhook'))->notify(new MonitoringMessage($message));
}
```

As you have stated yourself, the Exception class implementation is not needed because it's not used.